# IOS HockeyApp always popup update alertview

Tags: ios, hockeyapp

I started a trial plan at HockeyApp.
From the moment is publish a beta release to everyone the app always show an alert dialog saying
"Update Available"
"HockeyDemo Version 1.0 (3) is available.

Why does it happen ? and how am i doing wrong ?
I want to publish the app to the store but now i'm afraid it will popup this message..

Any inputs ? Thanks

Comment: As I remember This pop up appears when you add new version of your app in HockeyApp page. remove new one(or use new) and message will disappear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This alert on shows up when distributing a beta build. It will not show up in builds that are distributed via the App Store. All beta specific features are automatically disabled when the app is distributed via the App Store.

When releasing a build to the App Store I'd recommend to only upload the dSYM to HockeyApp. That is enough for getting symbolicated crash reports.

Comment: I though that I need to disable hockey app integration before submitting the app to apple, do  I need to ?

Comment: You don't have to, as the SDK disables the popup itself when it detects it is running from a build distributed via the store.

Comment: is there any way to disable this popup from dashboard itself on Hockeyapp ?? Even for beta builds ?

Answer (score 10):

The pop up will not come in the live version.

But to be on the safer side i would recommend you to use this sample code below

```
[[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager] setDisableUpdateManager: YES];
```

This will disable the pop up in the app

Comment: no need since 3.8.3: https://support.hockeyapp.net/discussions/problems/73667-will-store-type-release-prompt-users-with-updates

Comment: Works great with multiple targets

Comment: Would this disable popup in all situations ?

Comment: @shaqirsaiyed yes

Comment: @JobinsJohn is there any way to disable this from Hockey App dashboard itself ?